# iPad user agent detection

Tags: javascript, php, ipad, user-agent

Is there a way of detecting the first generation iPad exclusively using either javascript or PHP?

I need to use some fallback javascript on the first gen iPads, as the newer iPads are fine.

Comment: http://www.enterpriseios.com/wiki/Complete_List_of_iOS_User_Agent_Strings

Comment: +1 - This is a reasonable question, dunno why someone gave it -1.  Though generally you should be checking features rather than devices.  Plus Apple give out the iOS details in the user agent not the generation (or type) of iPad.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you can detect iPad with the following.

```
if (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPad')) {
   echo "Its an iPad";
}
```

Comment: I can detect all iPads, just wanted to get the first generation. Anthing lower than 5.1.1. Preferably in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    if (/Apple-iPad/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        //iPad first generation detected!
    }
</script>
```